# Pharo dependency hell

Tags: dependency-management, smalltalk, pharo

I am trying to develop a simple project in Pharo, and I would like to add its dependencies in Metacello. My project depends on Glamour, Roassal and XMLSupport.

A way to cleanly install my project is to install the dependencies by hand first. Following the book [Deep into Pharo](http://pharobooks.gforge.inria.fr/PharoByExampleTwo-Eng/latest/PBE2.pdf) one can do

```
Gofer new
  smalltalkhubUser: 'Moose' project: 'Glamour';
  package: 'ConfigurationOfGlamour';
  load.
(Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfGlamour) perform: #loadDefault.

Gofer new smalltalkhubUser: 'ObjectProfile'
  project: 'Roassal';
  package: 'ConfigurationOfRoassal';
  load.
(Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfRoassal) load.

Gofer new
  squeaksource: 'XMLSupport'; 
  package: 'ConfigurationOfXMLSupport';
  load.
(Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfXMLSupport) perform: #loadDefault.
```

and then my project will work fine.

I have tried to create a `ConfigurationOfMyProject` using the Versionner, and I have added  Glamour, Roassal and XMLSupport as dependencies, using the version that are currently installed in my image (2.6-snapshot, 1.430 and 1.2.1 respectively).

The problem is that I am not able to load my project using Metacello in a fresh image. The project loads fine, but whenever I try to load my classes I get method missing errors in Glamour. Moreover, it is apparent that something is different, because even the world menu has different entries.

I have tried other combinations of versions, including using the stable Glamour (2.1) but I have obtained more errors, including not even being able to open the project in the Versioner (it complains about a missing Roassal name).

What is the correct way to add these dependencies cleanly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I want to highlight that if configuration is in class *ConfigurationOf<proj-name>* you can load it as using `#configuration` message:

```
Gofer new
  smalltalkhubUser: 'Moose' project: 'Glamour';
  configuration;
  load.
(Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfGlamour) perform: #loadDefault.
```

A I don't see your project, I can just suggest you to write configuration by hand. There is an easy tutorial called [Dead simple intro to Metacello](http://sleepycoders.blogspot.ch/2013/10/dead-simple-intro-to-metacello.html).

According to your description it should be something like:

```
baseline01: spec 
  <version: '0.1'>

  spec for: #common do: [  
    spec blessing: #release.
    spec repository: 'your repo url'.

    spec 
      package: 'YourPackage' with: [
        spec requires: #('Glamour' 'Roassal' 'XMLSupport') ].
    "also maybe you have a couple of packages that depend on different projects"

    spec project: 'Glamour' with: [
      spec 
        className: 'ConfigurationOf Glamour';
        repository: 'http://smalltalkhub.com/mc/Moose/Glamour/main';
        version: #'2.6-snapshot' ].

    spec project: 'Roassal' with: [
      spec 
        className: 'ConfigurationOfRoassal';
        repository: 'http://smalltalkhub.com/mc/ObjectProfile/Roassal/main';
        version: #'1.430' ].

    "and same for XMLSupport" ].
```

Also you can try to load #development versions, as I have an impression that projects like Roassal and Glamour have very outdated stable versions. Also please note that Roassal2 is actively developed and will replace original Roassal in Moose platform, maybe you want to consider using it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still have a problem, though, since I have numerous outdated versions of ConfigurationOfMyProject in the image. Is there a way to delete everything and restart cleanly?

Comment: Ok, I managed to make it work. First, I unloaded ConfigurationOfMyProject from the image, then I removed it manually from the package cache and the repository, and finally I was able to start fresh

Comment: Still, I have one question. After loading my project in a fresh image - which now works - the world menu is slightly different: the Roassal elements are not in their own submenu. If I load Roassal as above (with Gofer) this gets fixed, but I get a warning that I am about to load a new version of Roassal and the working copy is dirty. Why is that? Is it because Glamour modifies it? I am a tad confused

Comment: Moreover, when I load my project in a fresh image, the version of Glamour that gets loaded at the end is 2.5-snapshot, while I explicitly had added a dependency on the 2.6-snapshot. :-?

Comment: @Andrea when you load roassal with Gofer you execute `(Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfRoassal) load` and #load in _ConfigurationOfRoassal_ loads **development** version which is newer than **1.430**. Also where do you see that Glamour is 2.5-snapshot?

Comment: After a few more experiments it seems that I am finally able to reproduce consistent results. It seems I had changed **the order** in which Glamour and Roassal are loaded, and this lead to different results. Still, it seems that when I load Glamour, then Roassal, then Glamour is dirty, and viceversa. Is there a cyclic dependency between the two?

Comment: @Andrea there can actually be something. You can ask on https://www.iam.unibe.ch/mailman/listinfo/moose-dev. Or ask question with [tag:roassal] and [tag:moose-technology] tags

Comment: Hi Uko. In a baseline you should not refer to numbered versions, only to symbolically numbered versions: #'release3.1' and similar. The baseline is supposed to describe the package dependencies, not exact version dependencies

Comment: @StephanEggermont thank you. I've just copied a template I had and forgot to change baseline to release version :)

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously discourage writing configs by hand - that is the assembly code of Metacello ;) Unless you are working on cross-Smalltalk-platform projects with platform-specific code (e.g. code for Pharo 1.4 vs Squeak 4.5) - an area which hasn't been explored yet, Versionner is the tool for you. I have written dozens of configs with it and have yet to run into a roadblock.

When you say you added them as dependencies, did you just add them as projects in the "Dependent projects" pane?

[image]

If so, you also have to specify which of your project's packages depend on them. To do this, you select the relevant package of your project on the "Packages" pane.

[image]

Now, click on the edit button with the pencil icon that just became enabled. In the dialog that appears, click the green `+` button and add the external projects of interest.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I had done. After quite a bit of experimentation, it looks like the issue was the order of loading between Glamourand Roassal. Apparently if I put Roassal first - which is what I had done - then Glamour loading would overwrite Roassal with a different version, which was the root of my issue. Strangely enough, if I first load Roassal and then Glamour, then it is Glamour that gets overwritten. I suspect there is a cyclic dependency, which is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying this in an old version of Pharo?

Roassal has been superseded by Roassal2, and the support for XML is on smalltalkhub, split into ConfigurationOfXMLWriter and ConfigurationOfXMLParser, both in PharoExtras.

If you load the right groups from Glamour you don't need to describe the dependencies on Roassal, as Glamour already depends on Roassal(2). That explains your cyclic dependency.

You have also run into the problem we've recently talk about on the pharo  mailing lists
that #stable is not a usable symbolic version name. In the Seaside/Magritte/Grease projects we've changed to using #'release3.1' style symbolic version names. That ensures that there is less of a ripple effect when progressing stable.

Snapshot versions should never be a dependency, they just describe what is loaded at the moment, and are basically not upgradable.

[edit]
Metacello by default tries to be smart about not installing older versions over newer. This works pretty well as long as things are not moved to different packages. So it's a bit of bad luck there that you ended up with a non-working combination.

Metacello support complex workflows, and different smalltalk projects (need to) use different workflows. It often takes some time to reach consensus on the best way to do things.

Roassal does not depend on Glamour, but you can create the cycle in your own configuration :)

Packages were moved from squeaksource to ss3 and smalltalkhub because the server had had stability problems. More recently, those problems seem to have been fixed. The xml support was split as it was noted that a lot of applications actually don't need both writing and reading of xml.

Once you have a working configuration, it might be a good idea to build and test it on the continuous integration server of pharo:  http://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution
If not your actually application, at least the open source parts as used by you. That way the Pharo, Glamour & Roassal teams can know if a change they make breaks something.

Comment: I am an absolute beginner with Pharo. I have use Pharo 3.0, and I have followed the instructions on PBE2 to install Glamour and Roassal. By the way, I understand that Glamour depends on Roassal, bu the viceversa? Unfortunately I have started my project depending on Roassal1, not knowing better and now it would take a little time to translate it to Roassal2. About the XML support: if I load the packages from SmalltalkHub, will I end with the same classes, or the two are different projects?